# How can I use HAL in recent versions of Ubuntu?

Tags: 10.04, startup, automount, udev, hal

I've found that HAL seems to be the only way to generate events when a CD/DVD/Blu-ray is inserted (if you know of a better way, please [reply to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76385/do-something-when-cd-dvd-blu-ray-inserted)), so I'm trying to get HAL running on my headless 10.04 server. It seems to work okay when I run it manually with `sudo hald --daemon=yes --use-syslog`.

The problem is that `hald` does not automatically run on startup (I assume because it's deprecated), and there's no sign of it in `/etc/init.d`.  What's the proper way to get HAL running at startup in Lucid and beyond? And do I have to worry about other things getting screwed up by having this deprecated software around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HAL is deprecated for a laundry list of reasons; [UDev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) is replacing it. Fortunately nothing should break because it was all routed through DBus anyway. There is no need to revive the dead.

To detect CD removal and insertion, listen for `DeviceAdded` and `DeviceRemoved` on the `org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device` bus. [The example code in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27948/usb-device-changes-using-udev-and-d-bus) should be helpful.

Comment: Hmm. I tried that example code, and got an 'unknown service' exception when I try to `get_object()`, as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142690/cant-connect-to-org-freedesktop-udisks-via-dbus-python). Per that link, I tried replacing 'SystemBus' with 'SessionBus' (X11 initialization error-- headless server!) and also 'SystemSession' (does not exist).

Comment: Update: The example code at the other end of your link should read `iface = dbus.Interface(proxy, "org.freedesktop.UDisks")` (instead of `...UDisks.Device`). Also, I found that udisks wasn't even installed on my system, so that was part of the problem :). All seems to be working now. Thanks!